# Minif for various elements in an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, coordinates

I have several x-variables in an array some of which are repeated because they have different y-values. Using excel VBA I want to get the min y-values for each x-variable. for example from the following set

```
x y
a 2
a 3
a 4
b 1
b 2
```

I want to get

```
x y
a 2
a 2
a 2
b 1
b 1
```

I can run a minif and then a lookup function. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Since you are using VBA, could you post the current method? (I'm curious how you are doing the `MinIf()` part.)  Also, would you be interested in a non-VBA solution, or not?

Comment: I haven't written the MinIf yet but I can. There is also one at http://www.bettersolutions.com/excel/EIK284/LN318711811.htm. Unfortunately I have a constraint of using VBA only, other wise I could have used SQL.

Comment: Another option is an array formula, which uses neither VBA nor SQL, and which is what I would tend to do. This was actually my question -- why not just an Excel formula? If that is acceptable, then see http://superuser.com/a/764447/52833.

Comment: That is because I am doing other manipulations on the data within VBA before this step and I don't want to send data back and forth. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: I suppose it's hard for people to suggest a solution that is simpler than your proposed solution, particularly since your proposed solution has not been built yet.  I can't think of a better approach myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge here is an adequate MinIfs function. I have created the below, where MinIfs(Minimum range, look up range 1, criteria range 1 [look up range 1+i, criteria range 1+i]).

Once you have defined your minimums, just loop through each cell in the x column, test for a or b, and fill the corresponding y cell with the MinIfs value.

```
     'Define MinIfs function
     Function MinIfs(MinRange As Range, ParamArray Criteria() As Variant) As Variant
            Dim n As Long
            Dim i As Long
            Dim c As Long
            Dim f As Boolean
            Dim w() As Double
            Dim k As Double
            Dim z As Variant

            'Error if less than 1 criteria
            On Error GoTo ErrHandler
            n = UBound(Criteria)
            If n < 1 Then
                'too few criteria
                GoTo ErrHandler
            End If

            'Define k
            k = 0

            'Loop through cells of Min range
            For i = 1 To MinRange.Count

            'Start by assuming there is a match
            f = True

                'Loop through conditions
                For c = 0 To n - 1 Step 2

                    'Does cell in criteria range match condition?
                    If Criteria(c).Cells(i).Value <> Criteria(c + 1) Then
                        f = False
                    End If

                Next c

            'Define z
            z = MinRange

                'Were all criteria satisfied and value to be preserved is numeric?
                If f And IsNumeric(z(i, 1)) Then
                    k = k + 1
                    ReDim Preserve w(k)
                    w(k) = z(i, 1)
                End If

            Next i

            MinIfs = Application.Min(w)

            Exit Function

     ErrHandler:
            MinIfs = CVErr(xlErrValue)

        End Function
```

Any questions, please ask.

Diedrich